# Using 2 different body background colors

Tags: javascript, html, css, background

What would be the best way of doing 2 different background colors?

Code:
https://playcode.io/test4343?tabs=index.html,preview

When it's first viewed it's one color,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7p3Gs.png

After you click on circle, if I wanted to give it a different color how would I do that?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9q3T1.png

```
body {
  background: #353198;
}
```

Comment: You appear to already have that working in your fiddle - when you click the top icon, the background changes colour. When you click it again, it changes back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```
document.getElementsByClassName("jacketa").addEventListener("click", myFunction());
function myFunction (){
document.body.style.background="red";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use an onclick function on the circle and then in that function include the following code.

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "YOUR_DESIRED_COLOR";
```